# Colourful makefile info command

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

Usually I am using `echo -e "\e[1:32mMessage\e[0m"` to print colourful messages out of the makefile. But now I want to print message inside of the `ifndef` block, so I am using `$(info Message)` style. Is it possible to make this kind of message colourful ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You can use a tool like `tput` to output the literal escape sequences needed instead of using `echo -e` (which isn't a good idea anyway) to do the same thing.

For example:

```
$(info $(shell tput setaf 1)Message$(shell tput sgr0))
```

Though that requires *two* shells to be spawned and two external commands to be run as opposed to the `echo` (or similar) methods in a recipe context so that's comparatively more expensive.

You could (and should if you plan on using the colors in more than one place) save the output from `tput` in a variable and then just re-use that.

```
red:=$(shell tput setaf 1)
reset:=$(shell tput sgr0)
$(info $(red)Message$(reset))
$(info $(red)Message$(reset))
```

Comment: @eric-melski Thanks. That was the code I had in my head it just failed to come out my fingers correctly.